# Debugging EntityDataSource

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql, sql-server

```
this.EntityDataSource1.Where = "it.Name like '%@Name%'";
```

Something is wrong in this where clause because it seem to be getting equal and not like.
The problem is that i want to view the SQL that is being called to the database to see what is the problem.

Can I do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to view the SQL, use SQL profiler ( http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187929(v=sql.100).aspx )

Comment: @rtp You can run SQL Profiler on your local machine against a network server. (I'm assuming SQL server here. You should add a tag for the SQL variety you're using)

Comment: can you please guide me on how to add a sql profiler.  What do you mean add a tag for SQL variety.  A, using Sql Server by the way.

Comment: In the SQL installation, if you choose complete management tools, SQL profiler is included there. You don't need to install the actual server to do this. I have added the sql-server tag to your question.

Comment: ok i got the Microsoft Management Studio connected to the database.  But dont seem to find the sql profiler.  I read that it should be under the "tool" menu but it isnt...

Comment: Try in the start menu, under SQL Server/Performance tools. If it's not there, and you have no PROFILER.exe in your sql BINN folder, you probably haven't installed it.

Comment: ok i don't have it :( and can't find a free download.  There was once one in google code but it seems it no longer there.